# Angular2 loading information when getting from database

Tags: angular, loading

We all know that angular2 can display "Loading" information like this:
`<component-selector>Loading...</component-selector>`

We know that "Loading..." will be hiden when component is loaded.

My question is, how could I use "Loading..." message in other situations, for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let offer of offers | async">
  <p><strong>Title:</strong> {{offer?.title}}</p>
  <p><strong>Description:</strong> {{offer?.description}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

I import offers in constructor but these information load like 1-2 seconds. I would like to display some "Loading" text to the time when they display. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an *ngIf right before the *ngFor like so:

```
<div *ngIf="!offers">Loading...</div>
<div *ngFor="let offer of offers | async">
  <p><strong>Title:</strong> {{offer?.title}}</p>
  <p><strong>Description:</strong> {{offer?.description}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is when you use async pipe but u just removed that. Your idea for normal subscription works well. Thank you.